# Pandas DataFrame: Filter out "flat lines" (values, that do not change for n rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-science

I want to filter out data points who's values are equal for at least n rows.

Specifically, detecting equal values for at least n rows and filter out all the consecutive equal data too.

Here an example with n = 6 and the flat line is 8 rows long:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'col1':[1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1'])
print df


          col1
    0     1          
    1     3          
    2     3          
    3     3          
    4     3          
    5     3          
    6     3          
    7     3
    8     3
    9     4
    10    1
    11    1
    12    1
    13    1
    14    1
```

I want to get the following pd.Series "flatline_filter":

```
    s          flatline_filter  
    0     1    True     
    1     3    False     
    2     3    False    
    3     3    False     
    4     3    False     
    5     3    False     
    6     3    False     
    7     3    False
    8     3    False
    9     4    True
    10    1    True
    11    1    True
    12    1    True
    13    1    True
    14    1    True
```

To the filter out those flat lines at some point:

```
df = df[flatline_filter]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
n = 6

df['flatline_filter'] = (df.groupby(df['col1'].diff().ne(0).cumsum())
                           .transform('size').lt(n)
                        )
```

Output:

```
    col1  flatline_filter
0      1             True
1      3            False
2      3            False
3      3            False
4      3            False
5      3            False
6      3            False
7      3            False
8      3            False
9      4             True
10     1             True
11     1             True
12     1             True
13     1             True
14     1             True
```

Answer (score 2):

Code like this is more basic:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
data = {'col1': [1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1'])

# Define the threshold 'n'
n = 6

# Create a boolean mask for consecutive equal values
mask = df['col1'] != df['col1'].shift(-1)

# Create a cumulative sum of the mask to identify consecutive equal values
cumulative_sum = mask.cumsum()

# Calculate the difference between consecutive cumulative sums
difference = cumulative_sum - cumulative_sum.shift(1, fill_value=0)

# Create a filter for values that appear 'n' times or less
flatline_filter = difference.ge(n)

# Add the 'flatline_filter' column to the DataFrame
df['flatline_filter'] = flatline_filter

print(df)
```

output:

```
    col1  flatline_filter
0      1             True
1      3            False
2      3            False
3      3            False
4      3            False
5      3            False
6      3            False
7      3            False
8      3            False
9      4             True
10     1             True
11     1             True
12     1             True
13     1             True
14     1             True
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
n = 6

seq_ids = (df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift())).cumsum()
counts = seq_ids.value_counts(sort=False).loc[seq_ids]

df.loc[(counts < n).values]
```

Output:

```
    col1
0      1
9      4
10     1
11     1
12     1
13     1
14     1
```